# Remove-SPServiceApplication Hangs

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am attempting to run the following Powershell command to remove a service application.  The command never returns and just hangs and hangs. Anyone now why?

Remove-SPServiceApplication -Identity  -RemoveData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint timer service was stopped causing the script to hang.